# Very Long String Eclipse Android

Tags: android, eclipse, string

I started Android Programming few days ago and make a simple application using JSON request.
I have some problems to print to the output console the content of a string.
Indeed, the JSON response is quite big (.length() return 93k ) and when I print it with System.out.println, there is only 4013 printed char.
How can I retrieve the whole string ? (Or write it to a log file) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be it will be better for you to output it on device screen? As *TextView* element.

Or write it in file, using solution like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228699/write-and-read-strings-to-from-internal-file).

Do not forget to add permission for that in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        />
```

For future, to parse JSON use classes from ***org.json*** package, they are very easy and helpful.

Comment: I used you solution, but write it into /data (it was just to see if the data were complete) and discovered in the same time the DDMS perspective which is really usefull.

Answer (score 4):

You can use recursion, for example

```
private void longMsg(String msg) {
    if (msg.length() > 4000) {
        System.out.println(msg); // or whatever you want
        longMsg(msg.substring(4000));
    } else {
        System.out.println(msg); // or whatever you want
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be the console buffer size set in eclipse.

`Goto Window -> Preferences -> Run/Debug -> Console -> Uncheck Limit Console output`

Comment: Thank you but I already have removed the Console output limit and this is not working